# "There is already an object named 'Categories' in the database" after moving db to another server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've connected to two MS SQL Server instances from SQL Server Managment Studio. Then I generated a script with all schema and data from original database with Task->Generate script...

After that I create new database with the same name on the target instance and run the generated script. So I get full copy of my original db on the new instance.

But when I change connection string in my application (ASP.NET MVC + Entity Framework) I get an error "There is already an object named 'Categories' in the database".

I connect to new db instance with SQL Managment Studio and can't see no any duplicate tables and any differences from original instance.

What can be the cause of such problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Justin, but I we didn't use edmx for my model.  The problem was with Entity Framework migrations. I have a line in my dbcontext constructor:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<StoreDbContext, Configuration>());
```

EF migration tried to create all tables once more.

So I just drop all tables in my target db, start app with new connection strings. Migration created all tables automatically. And after that I just transfer the data from original db.

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is a problem in migration process, run add-migration command in "Package Manager Console":

```
Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
```

do some changes, and then update database from "Initial" file:

```
Update-Database -verbose
```